# How to specify play mode (prod, dev) when starting a "dist" application

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I'd like to know how to start a packaged play v2.3.7 application (created by the **`dist`** command) in **`Prod`** and **`Dev`** modes.

We create our distributable artifact using **`sbt dist`**, which produces a zip file according to [these instructions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist). We copy the zip file to the machine it will run on, unpack it, and start it according to the instructions on [that page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist). However, it always starts so that **`Play.isProd`** evaluates to **`true`**.

When developing our application, we can start it using **`activator start`**, which causes **`Play.isProd`** to return **`true`** , or **`activator run`** / **`activator test`**, which cause **`Play.isProd`** to return **`false`**.

We'd like to know if there is any way to start the packaged application and be able to control the state of **`Play.isProd`**, so that we can have a test instance running on our test server, and a prod instance on our prod server.

Our current workaround is to have a custom setting in **`application.conf`** and examine that using **`Play.current.configuration.getBoolean("play_mode").getOrElse(true)`**. I feel we should be using the built-in functionality instead.

Comment: Any update on how to run the `dist` task to produce a binary for running the app in `DEV` mode?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand your questions, but here goes.

My spontaneous recommendation would be to use environment variables, as this always decouples configuration from code, and binds specific configuration to machine/environment.

But to answer your question  :)

It is possible to have an additional .conf files and set the one to be used on start/run:

```
activator start "-Dconfig.resource=dev.conf"
```

Alternative if this is for a temporarily fix you could override specific configuration keys directly from command line:

```
activator start "-Dapplication.some.conf=override -Ddb.default.password=some_pass"

// This might even work, not sure
activator start "-Dapplication.mode=DEV"
```

Read more:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the **`isProd`** flag means something completely different from what we assumed: it only controls if the application runs with or without class-reloading. In other words, our "workaround" is actually the correct way to get what we want.

I'll leave this open for a while in case someone has anything more to add, but to the best of my knowledge this can be closed now.